# Multiple stored procedures within stored procedure, returns only first stored procedure output variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to mysql, and I am trying to use multiple stored procedures within stored procedure (sort of like a nested stored procedure). My resultant output is a null set any help would be appreciated

My stored procedure code block

---

```
Outer stored Procedure
```

---

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `test`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetHsi`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `GetHsi`
(
IN subregion VARCHAR(255),
OUT inc DOUBLE,
OUT dcl DOUBLE
)
BEGIN
CALL GetSubrgnSntmt('I', subregion, @Inc_Sntmt);
CALL GetSubrgnSntmt('D', subregion, @Dec_Sntmt);

SELECT @Inc_Sntmt INTO inc; 
SELECT @Dcln_Sntmt INTO Dcl; 
SELECT inc, dcl; 

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

```
inner stored Procedure
```

---

```
USE `test`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetSubrgnSntmt`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `GetSubrgnSntmt`
(
IN Sntmt VARCHAR(25),
IN subregion VARCHAR(255),
OUT sub_Sntmt INT 
)
BEGIN

DECLARE Total INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE subtotal INT DEFAULT 1 ;
DECLARE sub_sntmt DOUBLE DEFAULT 1; 

SELECT COUNT(Cust_Id) INTO Total 
FROM test.`jnk_test`
WHERE buy_cty = subregion ;

SELECT COUNT(Cust_Id) INTO subtotal
FROM test.`jnk_test`
WHERE Sntmt_2 =Sntmt  
AND buy_cty = subregion ;

SET sub_Sntmt  =  (subtotal / total) * 100;
SELECT sub_sntmt; 

END$$
DELIMITER
```

---

```
Output
```

---

```
CALL gethsi('central hyderabad',@inc, @dcl);
SELECT @inc, @dcl;

===========
@inc| @dcl
===========
null| null
```

I am struck on this and not able to proceed at this juncture I am not sure where I am going wrong kindly help.

Comment: Please don't tag MySQL questions with SQL Server.

Comment: The first question that you need to answer is whether the inner procedure works properly when called on its own.  You are doing some unnecessary shuffling of values around among variables, and you have some case mismatches in your identifiers (e.g. Total vs total), but none of these things should be breaking the code.  Does the inner proc work properly by itself?

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for pointing that out, i will refrain mis tagging in future .. thanks

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for picking this up i will note the points you made.. inner Proc works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the internal stored procedure. The output parameter `OUT sub_Sntmt INT` is also defined as a local variable `DECLARE sub_sntmt DOUBLE DEFAULT 1;`. One option is to remove the local variable.

[13.1.15. CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html)

> - Parameter names are not case sensitive.

[13.6.4.1. Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html)

> - Local variable names are not case sensitive.

Also check the definition of data types to avoid problems.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetSubrgnSntmt`(
IN `Sntmt` VARCHAR(25),
IN `subregion` VARCHAR(255),
OUT `sub_Sntmt` INT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE `Total` INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE `subtotal` INT DEFAULT 1;
    -- DECLARE `sub_sntmt` DOUBLE DEFAULT 1;

    SELECT COUNT(`Cust_Id`) INTO `Total`
    FROM `jnk_test`
    WHERE `buy_cty` = `subregion`;

    SELECT COUNT(`Cust_Id`) INTO `subtotal`
    FROM `jnk_test`
    WHERE `Sntmt_2` = `Sntmt`
    AND `buy_cty` = `subregion`;

    SET `sub_Sntmt` := (`subtotal` / `total`) * 100;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8f9b/1)</kbd>

Comment: Wchiquito,.... This simply awesome... code works like a gem...thanks a ton for making my weekend